# What is the icon next to Spotlight in menu bar, and how to remove it?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

What is this icon 
[image] in OS X menu bar and **how do you remove it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Notification Center icon.

To remove the Notification Center, paste this script in AppleScript Editor and then run it...

```
display dialog "Notification Center" buttons {"Remove", "Display"} default button 2
if the button returned of the result is "Remove" then
    tell application "Terminal"
        set currentTab to do script ("launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist")
        delay 2
        do script ("killall NotificationCenter") in currentTab
        delay 3
        quit application "Terminal"
    end tell

    say "Notification Center has been removed successfully."

else
    tell application "Terminal"
        set currentTab to do script ("launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist")
        delay 5
        quit application "Terminal"
    end tell

    say "Notification Center has been restored successfully."

end if
```

Save this script as an application if you regularly want to remove or display notification center.

Answer (score 2):

This is Notification Center icon. You can get rid of it using http://www.macbartender.com app.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I also found a command line approach http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/06/disable-notification-center-remove-menu-bar-icon-os-x/

Comment: That does more than remove the icon. It unloads Notification Center completely, which is not exactly the question you asked. Just wanted to clarify for future visitors.

Comment: @samh You're referring to `MonoThreaded` comment to be exact :) Accepted answer also removes NC completly not only the icon.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable it only with some tools, Bartender is not free, but a nice tool.

I think you will love [NCBackgrounder](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/44252/ncbackgrounder) - after the Installation you can disable Notification Center (or Customize it) and the best thing is - it's completely free.

I hope this works for you.

Answer (score -3):

On Mac:

1) Click Chrome in your top menu bar.
2) Select Hide Notifications Icon from the drop-down menu.

Comment: I'm fairly certain this does not address the question being asked. Want to add some more detail so it doesn't get down voted?