# Disable notification center in Yosemite

Tags: macos, notifications

I tried several solutions to disable completely the notification center in Yosemite.
For example, see https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/57477/104881 or https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/139171/104881.

These solutions disable the notification panel, but, in Yosemite, the notification icon of the menu bar is still there.

**How can I remove the menu bar icon ?**

I know the bartender software can do that but I am looking for a solution which does not require addind another app.

EDIT:

- I have already tried to remove NotificationCenter.app in /System/Library/CoreServices.
- I also tried the following command:

  launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.notificationcenterui.plist; killall NotificationCenter

These two techniques remove the notifications but do not remove the icon.

Comment: If you are looking for the same situation - hiding the notifications, it's best for you to edit / promote the existing questions. If you can edit your question so that it's asking something different than the other questions we can reopen this thread.

Comment: This is not really the same situation @bmike, because it's in Yosemite. The other techniques work in Mountain Lion, but not in Yosemite. Please do not flag it as a duplicate.

Comment: I've reopened it, but if you list the exact solutions you tried, it will help others know how to help you. The community still might close this as a duplicate if it's not edited to be more clear how it differs from the other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Like the spotlight search icon, the notification centre icon cannot be removed from the status bar using OS X. You should use the bartender program to hide that icon.

It works with Yosemite and has the [feature you seek](http://www.macbartender.com/#features):

> With Bartender you can hide or move the Notification Center menu bar item, but still use Notification Center.

Comment: Thank you for this comment. I already commented on bartender in my question: I do not wish to use it). Furthermore, you claim that you cannot remove the icon from the status bar, but this used to be possible in mountain lion. I am looking for a similar technique that would work in yosemite.

Comment: How could you remove it in mountain lion then?

Comment: the two techniques that I cite in my question remove both the program and the icon. In Yosemite they remove the program, but not the icon.

Answer (score 2):

Solution (not perfect because it leaves the space of the icon in the menu bar, but it's always better than nothing), type this in the Terminal and confirm with your password :

```
sudo rm System/Library/CoreServices/SystemUIServer.app/Contents/Resources/menuitemNormal.pdf
```

And reboot your computer (or close and reopen your session).

Explanation :

I was searching for the same thing, so I searched where the file image of the icon is in the system, and it was not hard to find it.

First, I looked for something related to the user interface in the Activity Monitor, and I found SystemUIServer. Next, I searched its emplacement in the hard drive, I used Show Package Contents, and I looked in the Resources folder. Bingo, the icon was this pdf file ! Next step was as simple as deleting it.

Comment: Shouldn't the command start with `sudo rm /System/`?